# How to set bash as the default shell in puppy linux?

Tags: puppylinux

I have just installed puppy linux and the bash package but cant seem to have the terminal start up with bash instead of sh

Comment: Tried using chsh: command not found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to change your login shell in /etc/passwd in all Linux distros. Below, an example line. Note how the last component points to a shell binary.

```
mkaito:x:1000:100:,,,:/home/mkaito:/bin/zsh
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to be the system-wide default shell, this series of commands (run from a root shell) will do it: `rm -f /bin/sh; ln -s bash /bin/sh`

Otherwise, editing the /etc/passwd file as @mkaito suggests will let you change the default shell for your user account.